# fade in and out loop with three divs in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I've used this 
http://jsfiddle.net/3KydB/
and tried to modify it for 3 divs:

```
window.switchIn = function () {
    $('.chart_1').fadeToggle(function() {
        $('.chart_2').fadeToggle(function() {
            $('.chart_3').fadeToggle(function() {
                setTimeout(function() {window.switchOut();}, 6000);
            });
         });
    });

}

window.switchOut = function () {
  $('.chart_3').fadeToggle(function() {  
    $('.chart_2').fadeToggle(function() {
        $('.chart_1').fadeToggle(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {window.switchIn();}, 6000);
        });
      });  

    });

}

setTimeout(function() {window.switchIn();}, 6000)
```

The first one fades in and out fine, then the second one fades in with the third one below it, then back to the first one etc.

Comment: i need it to run through all three, rather than showing the first one, and then the other two together, then the first one again etc

Comment: If all of the charts are at the same level, you could place them in a container, set them as hidden with CSS and then create a simply function that will fade in the first child, fade it out then prepend it to the end of the container - you then simply repeat the function.

Something like 
function rinse() {
$("#container div:first").fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut().prependTo($("#container"));
}

var timer = setInterval(rinse(), 3000);

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/UwNzB/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you would want something like the following: http://jsfiddle.net/mEeAt/

```
window.switch1 = function () {
    $('.chart_3').fadeToggle(function() {
        $('.chart_1').fadeToggle(function() {
            setTimeout(window.switch2, 6000);
        });
    });

}

window.switch2 = function () {
    $('.chart_1').fadeToggle(function() {
        $('.chart_2').fadeToggle(function() {
            setTimeout(window.switch3, 6000);
        });
    });
}

window.switch3 = function () {
    $('.chart_2').fadeToggle(function() {
        $('.chart_3').fadeToggle(function() {
            setTimeout(window.switch1, 6000);
        });
    });
}

setTimeout(window.switch2, 6000)
```

So each function is responsible for fading out the active element, fading in the next element, and setting a timeout for the next function in the cycle.

Of course there is a lot of repeated code here, so you would probably be better off creating a function to make this more generic: http://jsfiddle.net/mEeAt/1/

```
function cycle(delay) {
    var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    var functions = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        functions.push(function (i) {
            var prev = i === 0 ? elements.length - 1 : i - 1;
            var next = (i + 1) % elements.length;
            return function() {
                elements[prev].fadeToggle(function() {
                    elements[i].fadeToggle(function() {
                        setTimeout(functions[next], delay);
                    });
                });
            };
        }(i));
    }
    functions[1]();  // start cycle by fading in the second element
}
cycle(6000, $('.chart_1'), $('.chart_2'), $('.chart_3'));
```